# Jquery mobile, change part of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change a part of a page, I know that this has been asked before but I cannot really find a good solution to my issue.

The red colour is the part of the page I want to change dynamically depending on what you click on the left side that is a panel.

**Image:** http://wstaw.org/m/2014/04/24/ask.png

**HTML Code:** http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7322513/

```
<body id="framework">
    <div data-role="page" class="page ui-responsive-panel">
    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1 id="titlepage">ICU</h1>
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <a href="#right-panel" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <!-- content that is replaced by ajax -->
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <h2>content</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <!-- Left menu panel -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="overlay" id="nav-panel" data-theme="b">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a" style="margin-top:-16px;" class="nav-search" id="nav">
            <li data-icon="delete" style="background-color:#111;" data-theme="b">
                <!--Removed data-rel="close" since there is a bug in jquery mobile https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1405 -->
                <a href="#closemenu">Close menu</a>
            </li>

            <li data-filtertext="Inbox">

                <a href="html/dummy.html">
                    <span class="ui-mail-icon-blue nav-ui-thumbnail"></span>
                    <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-corner-all" id="mail#">2</span>
                    <h1 class="ui-li-headline">Inbox</h1>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc" id="gotMail">Du har mail!</p>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li data-filtertext="Startsida">
                <a href="html/dummy2.html">
                    <span class="ui-start-icon nav-ui-thumbnail"></span>
                    <h1 class="ui-li-headline">Startsida</h1>

                </a>
            </li>

            <li data-filtertext="Översikt">
                <a href="html/dummy2.html">
                    <span class="ui-overview-icon nav-ui-thumbnail"></span>
                    <h1 class="ui-li-headline">Översikt</h1>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Antal elever (2)</p>

                </a>
            </li>

            <!--Nav list divider-->
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-button ui-li-divider ui-bar-a ui-li-has-count">
                Avdelningar
                <span id="departments#" class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-corner-all">2</span>
            </li>
            <!--/Nav list divider-->


            <!--Auto generated departments-->
            <li data-filtertext="Testpage">
                <a href="html/dummy.html">
                    <span class="ui-department-placeholder nav-ui-thumbnail"></span>
                    <h1 class="ui-li-headline">Avdelning 1</h1>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Antal elever (2)</p>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li data-filtertext="Testpage2">
                <a href="html/dummy2.html">
                    <span class="ui-department-placeholder nav-ui-thumbnail"></span>
                    <h1 class="ui-li-headline">Avdelning 2</h1>
                    <p class="ui-li-desc">Antal elever (3)</p>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
function loadPage(page, title) {
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
        $("#titlepage").html(title);
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("Gick inte att ladda");
    });
}
```

I have done my own ajax loadpage that works but is there a way to use the jquery mobile internal since it feels like a hack.

**Conclusion,** is there a way to do this better? and *how* should i load script for each page, using the main-page header to load all of them at once or is there a way to load the script when that content is loaded.

Im using 
**Jquery** jquery-2.1.0
**JqueryMobile** jquery.mobile-1.4.2

Best Regards

Comment: **Jquery Code:** http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7322541/

Comment: @Anton had few issues with it detecting it but managed to get it now.

Comment: Are you using single or multi-page model? and which jQM version are you using?

Comment: I personally don't see anything wrong with your current approach, for page content at least.  As for scripts, you could use `$.getScript()` to load them with the page.  You then have to think about issues like "do you want to load the script every time the page is loaded, or just the first time" and "does the script have a piece of code that runs when it's first loaded.  If so, do you want it to run again later?"  I'd ignore all that for now though and just say, "Yes" to your current method of loading sub-pages.

Comment: @Omar I'm using single page model at this time. Sorry forgot to mention what version of jquery...

Im using jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js and jquery-2.1.0.js

Comment: single page means each page in a different document/file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have done my own ajax loadpage that works but is there a way to use the jquery mobile internal since it feels like a hack.

jQuery Mobile is based on Ajax Navigation; it uses Ajax to retrieve pages, load them into DOM and then *initialize* them before showing them. This been said, when you use Ajax to load external data, you are doing it the right way.

You can use `$.ajax()`, `.load()` or `$.get()`. However, bear in mind that you need to manually *initialize* data retrieved - in case it contains jQM widgets - using *enhancement methods* e.g. `.enhanceWithin()`.

> Should I load script for each page, using the main-page header to load all of them at once or is there a way to load the script when that content is loaded.

As you're using *Single Page Model*, it is safer (maybe you should) load all JS libraries and style sheets in `head` for each and every page. Nevertheless, jQM will load those links only **once** on first page's initialization, the rest of pages will be loaded/retrieved via Ajax. jQM loads **first** `data-role=page` it finds in any *external* page and neglects any thing else.

Why to load all JS and style sheets? Is to get jQM working again in case a user *refreshes* current page. In this case, the current *refreshed* / *reloaded* page becomes **first** page.

#### Binding events and adding listeners:

When using jQM, you need to stay away from `.ready()` and/or `$(function(){})` and use [*Page Events*](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/). Except for some cases e.g. using *External* toolbars, panels or popups. Those *External* widgets need to be *initialized* manually on first run before page is loaded.

```
$(function () {
  $("#ExternalPanel").panel();
});
```

As for adding listeners, use `pagecreate` event.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
  $("foo").off("click").on("click", function () {
    /* do something */
  });
});
```

You need to remove `.off()` previous bindings and then `.on()` add them again, since *external* pages go through `pagecreate` whenever they are shown. Because jQM removes *external* pages from DOM once hidden.

One final point on appending elements to active page. You need to be specific as where you want to add those elements retrieved by Ajax.

```
var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
$.get("URL", function (data) {
    $("#foo", activePage).html(data).enhanceWithin();
}, "html");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cfqMU/show/) <sup>(1)</sup> - [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cfqMU/)**

<sup>(1) Click "inbox"</sup>

Comment: I got it working however I cannot find a good way executing the script on the second page with events. 

None of the jquery mobile events will run when i load the page contents with $.get()

Comment: @CommanderAlchemy I forgot to mention that if you have custom JS for other pages, you need to place them inside `data-role=page` div of that page.

Comment: Hm, if I don't have a page div on the other document the script works if i don't use any events. 

When I added a div with data-role=page then the bindings start acting. When clicking on my menu on the panel it seems its executing 

`(document).on("pagecreate", "#overview", function () {` with incrementing effect on each click. Do I need to have an `(document).off(....).on(...)` aswell ?

Comment: @CommanderAlchemy if it's an _external_ page and `data-dom-cache` isn't set to `true, then you need to remove previous bindings or use `.one("pagecreate"` instead of `.on`

Comment: Thank you I'm starting to get an understanding of this I think =)
Since I'm injecting code into contents, should the new page also have a data-role=page and should they also need to contain headers/footers div roles?

I tried that but then it stops rendering the contents. Removing the div with data-role=page and it works so something with the enhanceWithin?

Comment: I have tried with refreshing the listview inside that page also switched the contents to the new updated spec not using data-role=content

The contents can be seen with inspect elements in chrome but it its not rendering when using data-role=page.

Comment: @CommanderAlchemy no, you dont have to wrap them in `data-role=page` because they aren't pages. You load contents/elements into a page. You need +2 rep to be able to chat :/ anyway, you can post a new question with how you're loading contents dynamically. I'll help you out.