# JqueryMobile - JS/Ajax fails loading first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm currently making a mobile website with JqueryMobile 1.3.2.
No specific problem, all seems to work perfectly with the library and all, but I have one tricky problem :

JqueryMobile is loaded, then I'm using scripts of my own. (Javascript, Jquery and Ajax)

- When I enter an Url in the address bar, no problem.
- When I go on a page with a link (I click on my site), my scripts fails loading.

  - If it fails, and I reload my page (F5), all works perfectly.

I don't understand, i've checked and re-checked everything, I don't get it...

Comment: Any chance we see it online? Any error in console when failing? `my scripts fails loading` unexpected path or what?

Comment: most likely you're using _Single Page Model_, you need to place JS code inside `data-role=page` div.

Comment: Can't show you, local only.
In fact, the scripts doesn't load when the page is loaded with AJAX (JqueryMobile doing this for any <a></a> link), I think that's why it is working when I reload the page, because, it's generated without Jquery mobile AJAX.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/a/22860434/1771795 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23272922/1771795

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, using different html/php files with JqueryMobile doesn't made any custom script working ? I just have to add a <div data-role="page"> containing my script in my page ?